# Display image in validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working in ASP.Net MVC. I have to submit a form, which i can validate, only by showing error messages. But i don't want to show `text` in case of error, rather want to show `image`. Please tell me how `images` can be displayed in ASP.Net Form validation process, not `text`.

Comment: Are you using jQuery unobtrusive validation?

Comment: Doing validation in server side code.

Comment: Do you want to show Image next to the controls (textbox, checkbox, etc.)????

Comment: yes i want to show images next to controls, place where error text is displayed generally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this
Your can create CSS like below

```
input[type="email"] {
    background: url('images/envelope.png') no-repeat center left 5px;
    padding-left: 50px; /* depends on width of envelope image */
}
input[type="email"].input-validation-error {
    background: url('images/envelope.png') no-repeat center left 5px, url('images/cross.png') no-repeat center right 5px;
}
```

Detail:- 
[MVC4 graphical validation for text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998057/mvc4-graphical-validation-for-text-box)